# Django: In one model I have used User model as foreign key, I want to autofill the username while creating my Model

Tags: django, select, orm, foreign-keys

```
class ReplyPost(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(CreatePost, blank=True,null=True, related_name='subject_post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #message = models.TextField(validators=[validate_post_word_count])
    message = models.TextField()
    create_reply_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_reply_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    reply_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='replier_post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have this model, On creating replyPost I want to fill reply_by with current user

I tried:

```
form.cleaned_data['created_by'] = request.username
```

After saving the form it didn't save username.

In had printed the form it show this field as   tag .. How can fill this as selected in Django form

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use commit=False? It allows you to make changes in form before saving.

```
comment = form.save(commit=False)
comment.reply_by = request.user
comment.save()
```

BTW next time use code block (```)